# Apt can't locate vgrind (present in old-releases but not new), needed for pretty-printing

Tags: printing

vgrind shows up in old-releases http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vgrind/ and is not available via apt (apt-get install errors with the message "unable to locate package vgrind").

How can one get vgrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant find it in the Ubuntu repositores, you can download it directly, go to a terminal and do this:

`wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vgrind/vgrind_8.1+20050830-1_amd64.deb` then install vgrind `sudo dpkg -i vgrind_8.1+20050830-1_amd64.deb` now it should work

Comment: Thanks; have accepted your answer but am curious about the apparent typo: vgrind_1.0-21_amd64.deb -> vgrind_8.1+20050830-1_amd64.deb

Comment: @user1823664 you are right that vgrind_8.1+20050830-1_amd64.deb is a better version, I just put the one that was on an old VM, I updated my answer